# regex to find "null" values from a column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, regexp-replace, snowflake-schema

I have a column `JSON_DATA`. The values within this column have an object type. It contains a json. This query works fine:

```
SELECT
    $1 AS "JSON_DATA"
 FROM TEST_TABLE
```

This is how the data might look like:

```
{
  "Type": "xxi",
  "Quantity": "null",
  "ContactPerson": "null",
  "Email": null
}
```

Some of the values within this field are "null". I want to search all occurrences of quoted "nulls" and replace/regex_replace them with proper NULL values.

Desired output result:

```
{
  "Type": "xxi",
  "Quantity": NULL,
  "ContactPerson": NULL,
  "Email": null
}
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE( $1 , "null",  NULL) AS "JSON_DATA"
 FROM TEST_TABLE
```

but I get an error that:

```
SQL Error [904] [42000]: SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 22
invalid identifier '"null"'
```

I believe its because "null", from the second parameter, isn't the correct regex for the task. How can I fix this?

Edit:

I also tried this:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE( $1 , '"null"',  NULL) AS "JSON_DATA"
 FROM TEST_TABLE
```

but instead of finding and replacing all "null"s within the json objects of each row, the end result is just NULL for all rows.

Comment: Do you want to replace the entire json field with NULL, when one of the values inside is "null"?

Comment: I want to find all occurrences of "null", and replace that "null" with NULL. See the updated qs for the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the double quotes need to be in a normal string

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE( $1 , '"null"',  NULL) AS "JSON_DATA"
 FROM TEST_TABLE
```

As you have it, the DB is looking for a columns named `null`, that what snowflake reads double quotes as.

You might also want to look at [STRIP_NULL_VALUE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/strip_null_value.html) and/or [IF_NULL_VALUE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/is_null_value.html)

### Showing how to butcher JSON via REGEXP_REPLACE

not that you should do this, but you haven't said what you really want to do:

```
SELECT 
    column1,
    parse_json(column1) as json,
    REGEXP_REPLACE( json::text , '"null"',  '"DOGS"') AS fiddled_string,
    parse_json(fiddled_string) as back_to_json_data_again
    
FROM VALUES ('{
  "Type": "xxi",
  "Quantity": "null",
  "ContactPerson": "null",
  "Email": null
}')
```

gives:

| COLUMN1 | JSON | FIDDLED_STRING | BACK_TO_JSON_DATA_AGAIN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| { "Type": "xxi", "Quantity": "null", "ContactPerson": "null", "Email": null } | { "ContactPerson": "null", "Email": null, "Quantity": "null", "Type": "xxi" } | {"ContactPerson":"DOGS","Email":null,"Quantity":"DOGS","Type":"xxi"} | { "ContactPerson": "DOGS", "Email": null, "Quantity": "DOGS", "Type": "xxi" } |

Comment: this just returns completely empty fields. Instead of finding "null" values and replacing them within the NULL, I only get NULL values in the fields all together

Comment: I also tried this: ```SELECT strip_null_value($1) AS "JSON_DATA_2" FROM TEST_TABLE ```but it doesn't change anything in the data

Comment: Please see the updated qs with the desired output result

Comment: this works with "DOGS" but how come it doesn't work with NULL? if I write NULL instead of dogs, instead of replacing it returns NULL as the entire value

Comment: If I replace it with ```'NULL'```, is the output a string or just NULL?

Comment: if you replace JSON `null` with `"quoted string"` it is now a string.

Comment: I want a NULL instead of DOGS. no quoted strings.

Comment: if you can make nothing into a DOG I am sure you have the powers of GOD to create whatever you wish if you would just look at what you can do.

Comment: I meant that it works with DOGS but not null. But anyways, I have figured it out myself now.