# invalid identifier '"null"' (snowflake)

Tags: sql, postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

My column $1 has a few "null" strings that I want to replace with NULLs. I am trying this:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE( $1 , "null",  NULL) AS "JSON_DATA"
 FROM NEW_TABLE
```

However, I am getting an error that:

```
SQL Error [904] [42000]: SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 22
invalid identifier '"null"'
```

This is the syntax I see in the documentation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71213258/regex-to-find-null-values-from-a-column

Comment: Double quotes are used for [identifiers](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html). Single quotes or dollar signs are used for [string literals](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-text.html#string-constants)

Answer (score 3):

the double quotes need to be in a normal string

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE( $1 , '"null"',  NULL) AS "JSON_DATA"
FROM TEST_TABLE
```

As you have it, the DB is looking for a columns named null, that what snowflake reads double quotes as.

You might also want to look at STRIP_NULL_VALUE and/or IF_NULL_VALUE

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the values are actually string with value null (without the double quotes), then your query should be:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE( $1 , 'null',  NULL) AS "JSON_DATA"
 FROM NEW_TABLE
```

As others already mentioned, double quoted strings are identifiers in Snowflake, use single quoted strings for actual string values.